# Executing the second query only the first query is executed

Tags: java, mysql

I want to make a function in java that executes two queries, in which I want to do this:

Example:

```
String s ="CREATE TABLE ClassRoom(ID int AUTO_INCREMENT PK ,
                              name char (2) not null,
                              section char (2) not null,
                              numberSt int not null,
                              )";
String s1 ="INSERT INTO ClassRoom VALUES (null,'5','A',25)";

pst = conn.prepareStatement(s);
               pst.executeUpdate();
               pst = conn.prepareStatement(s1);
               pst.executeUpdate();
```

I want to put some values in the table when I create the table.
The first time it works perfectly, but the second time `s` is not called as there is IF NOT EXISTS, but the `s1` is called again another time.

I want the `s1` to be called only if the `s` has been executed or the table has been created. IF the table already exists i don't want to call `s1` query.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your SQL database the easiest way will be to use an `upsert`. This inserts the data already if it doesn't exist, updating otherwise. You would need to remove the generated key and use a compound key from whatever values uniquely identify the room though.

Comment: Sorry can you make an example .. i have never used a upsert so have no idea how to do that.

Comment: thnx ;)
i will try to understand it ;)

anyway i got to solve that problem just removing IF NOT EXISTS from the CREATE TABLE Query.
If the table already exists it goes to the Exception directly surpassing the second query. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the table exists with the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'yourdb' 
    AND table_name = 'ClassRoom'
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to test if the table has been created.

```
boolean existsTable = false;

//  use significative variable names... always!
String createQuery = 
            "CREATE TABLE ClassRoom( " +
                                   "ID       int  AUTO_INCREMENT PK, " +
                                   "name     char (2) not null, "      +
                                   "section  char (2) not null, "      +
                                   "numberSt int      not null, "      +
                                   ")";

String defaultValuesQuery ="INSERT INTO ClassRoom VALUES (null,'5','A',25)";

String checkTableQuery = "SELECT * "                       +
                     "FROM information_schema.tables " +
                     "WHERE table_schema = 'yourdb' "  +
                     "AND table_name = 'ClassRoom' "   +
                         "LIMIT 1;";

PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(checkTableQuery);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

// if the check query returns some value then table exists!
if (rs.next()) {
    existsTable = true;

// if table don't exists, create it 
} else {
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(createQuery);
    pst.executeUpdate();
}

// execute query only if table exists
if (existsTable) {
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(defaultValuesQuery);
    pst.executeUpdate();
}
```